# fixed header table not occupying the full screen

Tags: html, css

I want to fix my table header. I found the answer from one of [StackOverflow's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers), However, I am having problems using that code. I want the headers size to be specified in percentage such that when user zooms-in/zooms-out the page, table adjusts it-self.

In this code, when the headers size is not matching the table data row's. If I comment out `position` tag in `CSS`, then header aligns itself with table data rows, but it makes it non-fixed header. Can some please help to get the headers aligned with table data rows and occupy the whole screen (size specified in % as various headers and corresponding data rows can have different width).

```
<style type="text/css">
table 
{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
thead 
{
    background-color:#000268;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
}
thead th 
{ 
    text-align:center;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: outset;
}
thead.th.hd1
{ 
    width:20% 
    text-align:center;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: outset;
}
tbody {
    color:#000000;
    text-align:center; 
    height:150px; 
    overflow: scroll; 
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}
tbody td 
{ 
    height:60px; 
    width:100px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: outset;
}
</style>
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th class = "hd1">Head1</th><th class = "hd1">Head2</th><th class = "hd1">Head3</th><th class = "hd1">Head4</th><th class = "hd1">Head5</th><th class = "hd1">Head6</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td><td>r1c3</td><td>r1c4</td><td>r1c5</td><td>r1c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try to put your code in JSfiddle

Comment: So many cells.. My eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working example:
I could not make it work with thead and tbody tags, so I made it with two simple tables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- After some testing, this code seems to work fine both in IE 10 and Firefox 21
 z-index is suported in IE 8 and should work if you use a !DOCTYPE declaration-->
<style type="text/css">
#space
{
position: fixed;
z-index: 51;
width: 99%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
#tblheader
{
position: fixed;
z-index: 52;
width:99%;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color:#000268;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 0px;
}
#tblbody
{
position: absolute;
z-index: 50;
width:99%;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
line-height: 1em;
margin-top: 85px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: auto;
}
#tblbody tr
{
min-height: 15px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
}
body
{
height: 3000px;
}
#tblheader tr
{
height: 60px;
}
td
{ 
width: 16%;
height: 40px; <!-- Here you can set the minimum height of the row -->
border-width: 1px;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="space">&nbsp;</div>
<table id="tblheader">
<tr><td>Head1</td><td>Head2</td><td>Head3</td><td>Head4</td><td>Head5</td><td>Head6</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="tblbody">
<tr><td>r1c1 other text that is automaticaly wrapped / the cell height increases automatically / other text that is automaticaly wrapped / the cell height increases automatically</td><td>r1c2</td><td>r1c3</td><td>r1c4</td><td>r1c5</td><td>r1c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr> <!-- I have copied some rows for test purposes -->
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just one question : How can I make my first column to be of larger size. I added `id` on the `td` of first header and added in CSS as `tblheader.td.abc
{ 
width: 30%;
height: 40px; <!-- Here you can set the minimum height of the row -->
border-width: 1px;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
word-wrap: break-word;
}`. But it doesn't seems to work. Appreciate if you help in achieving the varying size of headers.

Comment: You can call a tag only by its id with # symbol (ex.: #abc); .abc means you are calling the tag that has the class set to abc. You can use .tblheader td #abc, but you can also simple use #abc. Below I have put a complete code where I have added #def id to the first cell in the first column of the second table, so it will be arranged the same as table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is of copy of what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#space
{
position: fixed;
z-index: 51;
width: 99%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
#tblheader
{
position: fixed;
z-index: 52;
width:99%;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color:#000268;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 0px;
}
#tblbody
{
position: absolute;
z-index: 50;
width:99%;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
line-height: 1em;
margin-top: 85px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: auto;
}
#tblbody tr
{
min-height: 15px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
}
body
{
height: 3000px;
}
#tblheader tr
{
height: 60px;
}
td
{ 
width: 14%;   
height: 40px; 
border-width: 1px;
border-style: outset;
text-align:center;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

#abc, 
#def 
{
width: 30%; 
height: 40px;
border-width: 1px; 
border-style: outset; 
text-align:center; 
word-wrap: break-word;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="space">&nbsp;</div>
<table id="tblheader">
<tr><td id="abc">Head1</td><td>Head2</td><td>Head3</td><td>Head4</td><td>Head5</td><td>Head6</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="tblbody">
<tr><td id="def">r1c1 other text that is automaticaly wrapped / the cell height increases automatically / other text that is automaticaly wrapped / the cell height increases automatically</td><td>r1c2</td><td>r1c3</td><td>r1c4</td><td>r1c5</td><td>r1c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can call a tag only by its id with # symbol (ex.: #abc)

Comment: Notice I have set the with of the first column to 30%. The width of the rest of the columns is divided by their number (99% - 30%)/(6-1)=~14%. If you want to set the width of each column separately, the you need to asign id's to each cell in the first row of the table and set the width of each column so that the sum of the width's will ad up to 99%.