# ASP.NET how to make slider for table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET table that gets lots of rows put into it. I want to have a slider to view more rows instead of making my page extremely long. This seemed like a basic task, but I cannot find any way to do this...

I would love to hear any ideas!

To be clear, my question is: how do I add a slider to my asp.net table?

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers

Comment: This is called a slider. http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Slider/Slider.aspx Please kindly show us what you have tried rather than we all guessing what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrew, that looks like it could be a good solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference,

```
    .FixedHeightContainer
    {
      float:left;
      height: 350px;
      width:100%; 
      padding:3px; 
    }
    .Content
    {
      height:224px;
      overflow:auto;
    }
```

along with:

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Results</h2>
      <div class="Content">
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" GridLines="Both" Height="350px" Width="80%">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>

                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Is what I used to create a table with a slider 
Thanks for all the comments :)

Nikita Silverstruk, your comment helped so much :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will exactly fit the bill, but check out the [ASP.NET Scrollable Table Server Control](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/pfc/aspnet_scrollable_table_server_control.asp)

Or were you asking for a slider pager control that will load more results for the user?

Comment: OP wants a scrollbar on a fixed-height table to keep the table compact, I believe.

Comment: Charlie's right, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your response, though :)

Comment: @user2548215, put a table in a div, give div a fixed height and whatever scrollbar settings you want (`overflow`)