# Table fixed header and first column css/html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has a large number of line and columns. But I would like to have the header fixed and the first column fixed. Here is a picture of what I need.

[image]

Only the pink part must scroll horizontally and vertically but the others must stay visible during the scrolling. My table is in a div.
First, should I use one table or four (the blue one, the red one, the green one and the pink one) ?

I have written this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5XWqj/1/

I tried to fix the header first but I wasn't a success

```
#container thead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

and something like this to select and fix the first column

```
#container tbody tr td:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

but it's not fixing about the div that wrap my table.
Maybe I will need some jQuery or JavaScript?

If anyone could help.

Comment: The answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers may also be useful here.

Answer (score 5):

May be you are looking for something like this:

http://zurb.com/playground/playground/responsive-tables/index.html

All you need is include the JS and CSS files and simply add `class='responsive'` to your table element.

I tried to implement that with your code, but there was some issue with rowspan, so tweaked it a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/UqYgq/3/

I think you also wanted vertical scrolling in similar fashion. Let me know if I should help with that?

Answer (score 3):

I solved same problem with only one table and DataTables plugin with FixedColumn extension. 
You can see demo of the extesion: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/

In my solution I have one table, in its **thead** section are rows I want to have frozen (you can you rowspan for the first cell). And the FixedColumn extension froze first two columns for me.

**DataTables plug-in init I used:**

```
duplicatesTable = $('.js-merge-duplicates-table').dataTable({
            //I want standard table look - no DataTables features but frozen header
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollY": "500",
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        });
        new FixedColumns(duplicatesTable, {
            "iLeftColumns": 2, //maybe you would need only one column
            "iLeftWidth": 350
        });
```