# PHP datatable with fixed headers and vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a PHP file that displays a grid table.  I need to fix the headers, but still be able to scroll horizontally. I would like to do this with straight CSS and no Javascript.

I have searched all over Google and SO. Here are a couple of pages closest to what I would like to emulate, but they use Javascript:

http://fixedheadertable.com/

http://handsontable.com/demo/fixed.html

Take a look at my code. Perhaps my code could be changed or something:

```
 <?php 
   $select = "SELECT * FROM `dispatch`";
   $query = @mysql_query($select) or die ();
   $resnum = mysql_num_rows($query);

   if($resnum == 0){
     echo "<div>Your search returned no results</div>";
   }
   else{
     echo "<table>\n";
     echo "<thead><tr>" .
     echo "<th>Update</th>" .
     echo "<th>BOL</th>" .
     echo "<td>Container</th>" .
     echo "<td>Status</th>" .
     *** there are like 15 more <th> headers ***
     echo "</tr></thead>\n";
```

The code directly above are the headers that I need to remain fixed, but they need to also scroll horizontally.

Here is the rest of the code for the actual data that is displayed in TD tags:

```
  while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== FALSE){
     echo "<tbody><tr>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[UPDATE]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[BOL]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[CONTAINER]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[STATUS]}</td>";
     *** again, there are like 15 more TD tags that showdata retrieved from query ***
     echo "</tr></tbody>\n";
  };
  echo "</table>\n";
 }
 ?>
```

If I forgot to close a tag or add a semi-colon, please let it slide.  Just know that this code works.

I just need to figure out how to fix the HEADERS and still be able to scroll them horizontally.

I know this can be done without javascript.  I've tried several different CSS methods to make this work.  I can get the header to stick, but it won't scroll horizontally.

I'm not really sure how to label the CSS so that it will display correctly.  I've tried `DISPLAY: BLOCK; TABLE-COLLAPSE: COLLAPSE; OVERFLOW: SCROLL;` and many other methods.

I just can't get the header to stick.

Any help would be appreciated.  Do I need to utilize DIVs within the table?  I've seen and tried that as well.  Perhaps the while loop in the middle of the table is throwing everything off.

Comment: The tags 'php' and 'mysql' have as much to do with this question as do 'electricity' and 'internet'.

Comment: `{$Row[UPDATE]}` should be `{$Row['UPDATE']}`, unless you actually HAVE `defined()`'d constants with those names

Comment: I have added a css tag. I didn't put a javascript tag because I want to do this without javascript. The HTML table is displayed via PHP and MYSQL, which is why I put those tags. Please accept my apologies for not putting the correct tags.

Comment: Your 'no results' `div` is closed as an `h2`. Every result row is in it's own `tbody`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS-Only Scrollable Table with fixed headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: @Adam, I fixed the H2 and the tbody issue.

Comment: @Arian, I've seen that post as well. It does not show a vertical scroll.

Comment: @JohnBeasley yes it does, look: http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/h6hfX/1/

Comment: @Arian... I'm all messed up. I meant a horizontal scroll.

Comment: @JohnBeasley You might want to change the title of this question then.... lol

Comment: @MarcB - You are wrong. You can't escape keys like that in an array. OP has the right syntax.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: You're wrong. Using `{}` syntax in dobule-quoted strings requires quoting string-based array keys. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double  (look for "Complex (curly) syntax")

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a recommendation (and cannot fit in a comment for obvious reasons). This looks much cleaner and is much easier to read. You normally want to keep your html and php as separated as possible:

```
 <?php 
   $select = "SELECT * FROM `dispatch`";
   $query = @mysql_query($select) or die ();
   $resnum = mysql_num_rows($query);

   if($resnum == 0){
     echo "<h2>Your search returned no results</h2>";
   }
   else{
     ?>
     <table>
     <thead><tr>
     <th>Update</th>
     <th>BOL</th>
     <td>Container</th>
     <td>Status</th>

     </tr></thead>

     <?php
     }
     ?>
```

Besides, what you had wasn't even valid php nor html. DON'T:`echo "<thead><tr>" . echo "<th>Update</th>"`. DON'T: `<div>Your search returned no results</h2>`