# Creating a sticky header on a thead

Tags: html, css

I have a table that can become come very long on the page so the header gets lost and so I thought a sticky header would fix that. You scroll down too far and the header is still there to let you know what the fields are.

I know the traditional ways of doing a sticky header with jQuery, but I wanted to try a different way with just css.

I found [this](http://www.red-team-design.com/position-sticky-might-be-the-next-best-thing) on the web and it is supposed to work, but I cannot seem to make it do what it is supposed to.

```css
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  top: 15px;
}
```

and help would be great or any other css tricks to help this work would be great.

I set up a jsFiddel over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwHnq/32/) of what my form looks like so you can get a good idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 27):

Unless there is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927) in Chrome you can't fix the `thead` directly. Therefore you have to fix it on the th element:

```
thead th {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Why you can't sticky the thead is beyond me. This sort of works, but you lose coloring and borders, etc.

Comment: You can add `position: sticky` to `thead` directly now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911737/2478821). The magic is in the `position: fixed`.

If you want to jump the gun: working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/ZxPeh/23/)

**EDIT**

I don't think you can do this *cleanly* without Javascript.
Yet, I was intrigued by the problem, so I made this solution. It uses a wrapper `div` around the data with `overflow: scroll`.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MsdN2/)**

Comment: I found a fiddle that uses a seperate `div`to achieve this.
See: http://jsfiddle.net/hGYkt/ You may be able to play around with it to apply it to a table.

Comment: When I tried to apply that to the table head though it fails. It's not really advisable to put a separate div around the thead, which is what I want to make sticky. Also my table can be anywhere on the page it's not the first thing on the page. I just want to be able to read the headers when you scroll down.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, that is the 'cleanest' way I can think of, using only CSS and HTML.

Comment: It seems interesting, but this has a little problem: it doesn't work well if the table needs elastic columns (elastic grids) for match automatically the width of the content. In fact the provided jsfiddle example has td fixed width. This is due to the fact that position: fixed css property "detaches" the element from the normal flow of the DOM. I hope in the future it will work in elastic grids too but at the moment it doesn't or I hope a better implementation in browsers with position: sticky, that of course is the future best solution for the original question

Comment: It means that without the css width property of the columns and the th elements their mutual widths no longer correspond. It means that with this approach elastic table grids aren't easy (or not at all) doable. The sticky property remains the best approach because doesn't have such a drawback (at least once full implemented by all modern browser, let's hope asap)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me to create a sticky thead on a table...

```
table ,tr td{
    border:1px solid red
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
table {
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with the difference I had to figure out how to make it work in a more complex case: the problem I was facing was how to make position sticky work if in the same page there are more tables, some of them with just one row into the thead element and others with 2 rows with th elements.

The solution I found was to use css pseudo classes **first-child** and **last-child**.

The following code show how to do the trick:

```
// 1st rule:
    thead > :first-child th, thead > :last-child th
    {
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 1;
    }
//2nd rule
    thead > :last-child th
    {
        top: 80px;
    }
//3rd rule
    thead > :first-child th
    {
        top: 50px;
    }
```

Let's focus on the 2nd and the 3rd css rule: you may be tempted to write them logically ordered as **first-child** and next the **last-child**, but it will not work properly. In this solution, **in order to work properly you must put the last-child of the 2nd:**

```
thead > :last-child th
```

**BEFORE the first-child that must be written as the 3rd rule:**

```
thead > :first-child th
```

even if at first look seems to be illogical.

So the above is a versatile code that works even if you have either 1 or 2 rows into different thead elements in tables in the same html page because css rules are applied by the browser from top to bottom and after it finishes parsing the html-css content you get the right look of your th elements. But **if you invert the 2nd and the 3rd it doesn't work anymore** because it is needed that in case it has to parse a single th into a thead the 3rd rule must overcome the 2nd one to work properly. In fact if you have a table in witch thead you put just one row into, you may have a problems using just

```
thead th
```

or inverting the 2nd rule with the 3rd rule in my code like

```
thead > :first-child th {...}
thead > :last-child th {...}
```

because when you have a single row the first-child is simultaneously the last-child too so the browser does a mess applying to it the 80px position form the top, that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent elements have "overflow" it doesn't work... unless you've set width/height and you're scrolling.

Other than that, this:

> position:sticky; top:0; // vertical

> position:sticky; left:0; // for horizontal sticky

is enough to work.