# How can I freeze THEAD with CSS only?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to freeze the `THEAD` section of my table so that as I scroll, the `THEAD` is always visible. I've accomplished this by attaching an event handler to the `scroll` event in jQuery which sets the `top` position of the `THEAD` to the scroll offset:

```
$(".scroll").scroll(function () {
    $("#header thead").css({"top": ($(".scroll").scrollTop()) + "px"});
});
```

You can see it in action at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ciaoben/aVT7W/268/)

Comment: Not with `CSS` alone, because it's for styling, there's no way to detect the scroll position, that's why you need Javascript, to detect when there was a scroll of a certain amount.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS-Only Scrollable Table with fixed headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: can you elaborate what is it you want to achieve ? I don't really get what you mean by "header refreshing every time i scroll"

Comment: He wants to freeze his headers to the top of the page.

Comment: don't use thead, use a div as table header, set it fixed on top/absolute top againts a container while the table has top-padding as much as the height of the header

Comment: Unfortunately the only really good CSS solution is a ways off: http://charliepark.org/css-only-sticky-headers/

Comment: could you please show me an example of that in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The ugliest alternate solution, at least no js and supported by most browser (no css3). [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVT7W/277/)
basically it `duplicate` the table, set the 1st table header only visible on top of 2nd table. The drawback is, because it is using fixed position, it wont scroll horizontally as the the table did. Maybe if you set the table width as same as window width, it should work properly. Just an alternative

Comment: ty for the comment... but the horizontal scroll of the header in this way doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes, it has fixed position against browser window. try resize the js fiddle into wider screen or re size the table to fit browser window. I'm using 1920px width monitor and if I stretch jsfiddle window to its widest width, all data is properly displayed without the need of horizontal scrolling

Comment: yes but i need that when i see on little monitor, it could be seen correctly, even with the horizontal overflow bar

Comment: Then using some js is your only solution. There are many good jquery plugin or js snippet you can find in google. They're also does not modify content (like I did with duplicating table)

Comment: i've tried to search but all i found it seems to fix the header to the top of the page.. not of a div... anyway ty for your answers!