# Fix table thead or fix first column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to fix my tables head (`thead`) as soon as someone scrolls down or fix the first column (`.first-column`) as soon as someone scrolls left or right. Below you can see an example of my table. It can contain about 100 columns and 1000 cells, that is why I need this.
I guess this is not possible with just plain css, but maybe I am wrong. Way or another, I would like to ask for help to get this right. I am using `jQuery 2.x`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> class="first-column"> </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> class="first-column"> </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> class="first-column"> </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> class="first-column"> </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  ...
    </tbody>

</table>
```

asdfasdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS-Only Scrollable Table with fixed headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: Same question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting table headers offset to fix position on scroll event

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.show();
    }
    else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedHeader.hide();
    }
});
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque) similar question asked on Stack.

Comment: Tried this already before. I had some problem with the `width` of the table. And it still doesn't solve my second request, scrolling left or right.