# tbody scroll TR dynamic

Tags: css, html

I need you to scroll the body and always see the header, the examples works with static TR, but my example are dynamic.

Can somebody help me.

Thank you very much.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sortable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat="column in $ctrl.columns" ng-class="$ctrl.selectedClass(column.variable)" ng-click="$ctrl.changeSorting(column.variable)">
    {{column.display}}
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-click="$ctrl.click({row:object})" ng-repeat="object in $ctrl.data | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.column:$ctrl.sort.descending ">
  <td ng-repeat="key in object" ng-class="selectedClassColum($ctrl.columns[$index].color,object[$ctrl.columns[$index].variable])"
      ng-if="key != '$$hashKey'">
    {{object[$ctrl.columns[$index].variable] | customFilter : $ctrl.getFilterOfColumn($ctrl.columns[$index].variable)}}
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers

Comment: Thank you, I had seen it. But it does not square well the headers with the columns

Comment: can you create a fiddle to show the problem?