# How do I create fixed vertical and horizontal tables in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a 2D table with fixed variables on the top and far left of the table. I have already added the horizontal and vertical headers, but I'm not too sure of how to fix them so that the viewer can scroll through the data.

CSS + HTML:

```css
.fixed-tables {
  position: relative background: white;
}

.fixed-tables th {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="table fixed-tables">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Hor. Header 1</th>
      <th>Hor. Header 2</th>
      <th>Hor. Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Ver. Header 1</th>
      <td>(null)</td>
      <td>(null)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ver. Header 2</th>
      <td>(null)</td>
      <td>(null)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ver. Header 3</th>
      <td>(null)</td>
      <td>(null)</td>
      <td>(null)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This doesn't quite work because the data and headers overlap one another. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with your relevant HTML code as well so we can help more easily

Comment: Sorry! I added my html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS-Only Scrollable Table with fixed headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually modeled my approach after the link you gave. My only issue is that I'm trying to incorporate vertical headers in addition to the one's on the top.

Answer (score 0):

I use datatables whenever I am trying to create tables with fixed headers or columns.  It is incredibly robust and offers what you're looking for.

https://datatables.net/

Comment: @newsharepointuser101 it's a great plugin that has great documentation.  It is a bit heavy but has been very useful over the years.