# Fixed table header disappears when the specific height value is removed

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table with fixed header and vertically scrollable body. Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers) solution on stackoverflow (first answer) which works well when there is a specific height value (in this case 200px). But I want my height value to come from my elements parent.

I used height:100%; and height:inherit; under ".scroll tbody" but neither works.

```css
.scroll {
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.scroll tr {
  display: flex;
}

.scroll td {
  padding: 3px;
  flex: 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 1px;
  word-wrap: break;
}

.scroll thead tr:after {
  content: '';
  overflow-y: scroll;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.scroll thead th {
  flex: 1 auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.scroll tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="scroll" width="400px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you use % with make you need to set a height to parent or it won't work

Comment: So you want the header row as large as the tbody? This is your expectation?