# Sticky header as in facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea to create a fixed header as we commonly see in the http://facebook.com ... the blue bar which is in the top of the website and in all the page. Please help me with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position fixed header in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975268/position-fixed-header-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

In your css add this in your header element:

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: i tried to add the fixed position but the div which follows are overlapping the header. that is my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position:fixed"></div>
```

This places a element on a fixed position on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position fixed which makes sure that the header always stay at the place you said it should you can read about position fixed here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp