# Page loads with layout pushed up

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

When my pages load, it's as if the content is pushed up and then when loaded it pushes back down.

It makes my website feel clunky. I'm stuggling to figure out how to make it stay where it is while loading.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design

Comment: you have use `sticky-container` class in header having a `height:67.4px`, is that height been given by you are applied by a plugin ?

Comment: I'm unsure, I think it could be a plugin since I can't find the height in any css styles

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the script you are using to make the header sticky. It is having to wait for the page to render so that it can get the height of the element with a class of '.top-bar-container' and append it to the element with the class of '.sticky-container' element.

I would suggest either finding a different plugin or see this other stackoverflow question for a simple implementation of a fixed header:  [position-fixed-header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10975357/3718675)