# How to prevent HTML elements from going under the header in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, header

[image]

I have a header with buttons `Profile`, `Train AI`, `Matches`, `Chat Icon` and you can see in the above example my `Name 1` element & others are going under the header. My CSS for my header is:

```
<Header
        style={{
            background: colorTheme.text8Color,
            position: 'fixed',
            zIndex: 1, // make every display under the header
            width: '100%'
        }}
    >
        {this.renderHeaderButtons()}
    </Header>
```

What can I do to prevent anything from going under the header?

Comment: how about setting a margin-top to div below the header, equal to height of header.

Comment: @Subin thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975268/position-fixed-header-in-html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53jr7esa/3/

Comment: You have to fixed the position of your header so after that your sub menu will expand and it will not go under your header.